# Page mapped write only allows reading

Tags: c++, c, linux, mmap

If I map a page as write only:

```
int* mem_location = (int*)mmap(nullptr, getpagesize(), 
    PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

cout << "Read @" << mem_location << ". This should segfault: " 
     << *mem_location << endl;

cout << "doesn't though??" << endl;
```

why doesn't it segfault on read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap):

> On some hardware architectures (e.g., i386), PROT_WRITE implies PROT_READ.

You should not depend on this behavior.

Comment: @sircodesalot Note that this may be caused by architecture limitations. If the architecture doesn't support write-only pages, so can't POSIX without an extra layer of indirection (which would incur a significant performance penalty).

Comment: Interesting. Much appreciated!

Comment: In fact, in my experience, platforms that do support write-only memory pages are somewhat less prevalent than those that don't, so it's not all that weird. The practical uses for write-only memory pages are not extremely common...